# How to display tabs in infowindow using Codeigniter Google Maps V3 API library

Tags: javascript, php, codeigniter, google-maps-api-3

I am using [Codeigniter Google Maps V3 API library](https://github.com/BIOSTALL/CodeIgniter-Google-Maps-V3-API-Library) to display markers from database on map and so far it works great.

Problem is that I have multiple markers with identical coordinates. So, for example, I have three markers at one location but on map I see only one and get only one infowindow.

I did research and found that It is possible to create infowindow with multiple tabs with [infoBubble](http://googlemapapitutorial.com/js/infobubble.js) JS library. [Here](http://jsfiddle.net/phpdeveloperrahul/hT8Kw/) is a good simple code for adding infoBubble and I wanted to start with just that for beggining.

I created simple contoller that displays map with one marker:

```
public function index()
        {
                $this->load->library('googlemaps');
                $this->load->helper('url');
                                    
                $config['center'] = "37.4419, -122.1419";
                $config['zoom'] = "12";
                $this->googlemaps->initialize($config);
                
                $marker = array();
                $marker['position'] = '37.429, -122.1419';
                $this->googlemaps->add_marker($marker);
                $data['map'] = $this->googlemaps->create_map();
                
                $this->load->view('maps_view2', $data);
        }
```

and it works fine. So now I added

```
$config['onload'] = 'var  infoBubble = new InfoBubble({
              maxWidth: 300
            });
    
            var div = document.createElement("DIV");
            div.innerHTML = "Hello";
    
            infoBubble.addTab("Tab 1", div);
            infoBubble.addTab("Tab 2", "This is tab 2");
    
            google.maps.event.addListener(marker, "click", function() {
              if (!infoBubble.isOpen()) {
                infoBubble.open(map, marker);
              }
            });';
```

to my controller. Basically it simply adds JS code snipet to `function initialize_map()`. I also added `<script type="text/javascript" src="<?php echo base_url() ?>src/infobubble.js"></script>` to my view.

Comparing example that I used for code snipet with my sites source code I get the same code but there is no infoBubble...

Would appreciate if someone could hepl me understand where is the problem.

Comment: You may try the suggested solution in this [SO post](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/8275996/codeigniter-google-maps-api-v3-close-infowindow) wherein, instead of generating an `infoBubble` for each marker, a variable was created and then infoBubble's content were passed through `google.maps.marker();`

Comment: Please also check if this [GitHub post](http://gkwelding.github.io/2010/08/03/google-map-library-for-codeigniter-example-usage-update/) will help.

Answer (score 0):

this should work

```
var infowindow = new google.maps.InfoWindow({
                      content:""
                    });
                        marker.setMap(map);
                        marker.addListener('mouseover', function() {
                        infowindow.open(map, marker);
                    });
```